# Statement macros in D

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor, d

I am porting some code I have written in C++ to D. At one point I introduced a convenience macro, that contains an assignment. Like

```
#define so_convenient(x) value = some_func(x,#x)
```

So I am using macros to

1. access the actual symbol and its string and
2. make an assignment.

How do I achieve this in D?

Comment: Macro like that is commonly discouraged in C++. People would prefer inlined function. Why? Because inlined functions are not only type-safe but also can't appear in ANY context.

Comment: @DejanLekic macro is needed for the stringize part

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `mixin` statement to convert a string into code at compile time e.g.:

```
mixin("value = 123;");
```

---

The following function will generate a string containing a statement which would be the closest equivalent of your C macro:

```
string soConvenient(alias A)()
{
    return std.string.format(
        'value = someFunc(%1$s, "%1$s");',
        __traits(identifier, A));
}
```

Which you would then use like this:

```
mixin(soConvenient!x);       // equivalent to 'so_convenient(x) in C
```

Comment: I prefer template mixing whenever possible. They are covered in the language reference on http://dlang.org .

Comment: the quotes needed to be corrected. Works like charm otherwise.

Comment: I'd use a `string soConvenient(string A);` instead, personally. Needs quotes at call site but otherwise just plain CTFE with no instantiations.

Unless the computation is expensive, in which case a template instantiation might work better given caching.